# Can a child image with a width greater than its wrapper (set to overflow:hidden) be dynamically horizontally centered?

Tags: html, css, image, center

So given the following [fluid image](http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images):

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150">
</div>
```

with

```
.container {
    margin: 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Is it possible to horizontally center this image in css, whilst the edges are overflowing, without setting it as a background-image?

sourcecode also here: http://jsfiddle.net/RWqha/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why This Is Hard To Do**

You are running into the imitation of the block formatting algorithm implemented by CSS to render the visual content.

Your container forms a block element and the image (an inline replaced element with computed dimensions) is positioned to the left and top edges of the parent container.

This can't be changed using any CSS properties unless you can hard code specific values for padding, margin, position or whatever that depend on the dimensions of the image being displayed.

Of course, this can be done with jQuery/JavaScript.  To some degree, that is why all these elegant image rotators and image galleries are built with JavaScript/jQuery.

**Try Media Queries**

If you allow yourself to make full use of HTML5/CSS3, you could try a media query that specifies CSS rules optimize for smaller screens.

I don't think that the effect is realizable with current CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit messy, but it works (tested only in Firefox). Forked example (try to resize frame): http://jsfiddle.net/GAFzc/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrap">
       <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150">
    </div>
</div>

.image-wrap {
     margin: 0 -999px;
     text-align: center;     
}
```

This solution are you looking for?

**UPD**

So, if we need a responsive image, that will adapt to container width, but still have a min-width value, and has to be *centred inside visible* part, we should use another way to rich that. I think, I've found solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/GAFzc/5/

HTML (the same):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrap">
       <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrap {
     margin: 0;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: -300px; /* Min width of image */
}
.image-wrap > img {
     position: relative;
     left: 150px; /* Half of min-width value */
     min-width: 300px;
     width: 100%;
     display: inline-block; /* or inline */
}
```

I don't actually understand how it works, but it works (tested in Chrome, FF, IE10,9). 
The main trick here is the using of text-indent. We "reserved" the space outside the left edge of the first line, and then use it to centre our image (left: 150px;). Or something like this :)

Comment: Looks good, but do you know how to get it to resize down to the 300px width? Because it doesn't do that anymore. Is it because of the margins?

Comment: The large negative margins effectively set the width of `.image-wrap` to 1998px+width-of-contained-image.  This solves the centering problem but not the sizing.  Good technique, however, good to keep in mind.

Comment: @MarcAudet, Ah right, so that's how it works. So I guess it's incompatible with the max-width:100% part since it never reaches 100%. But you're right, nevertheless a very useful technique.